# windows wpf MVVC pattern, how to fit code logic in that pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working now with converting existing winform app to WPF. I've never coded anything using MVVC pattern before and I have a hard time trying to figure out how to correctly set models, viewmodels and views in my specific case.
App that I want to convert is used for communicate with physical devices using serial port. 
Let's first start with existing winform app. Almost any of the logic is in separate .dll file that expose interface which winform consumes. There are  really no "code behind" while displaying data because dll already expose everything that is needed. There are only some additional functions in GUI for manipulation of the data, saving current data etc.

The thing is that I really don't understand how to fit this nicely in MVVM. As model as I understand I will need to create some let's say device that will have all the properties that are changeable and readable. And first question, if model needs to be concrete class or it may be some interface (which I already have) or maybe abstract device class (that implements this interface)?

Second question about ViewModels. I understand that ViewModel is somehow used for "glue" model data to view. And from that perspective in ViewModel I can put all the code that as a result format data from device to output it in some nice formats that will be easily databinded to View. But, here is a quirk. I think that this inteface that I'm now using in that .dll file fits nicely to be databinded in gui (or maybe not?).

Another question is about View itself. I understand that View wouldn't be aware of model etc. But could I put in view that code that I already have in winform GUI? (for saving data to csv files, for doing some measurements etc) or maybe I will need to create another model (I have no idea what it may be looks like).

And the last question is where to put all the logic for using serial port, for concrete implementation of all functions etc. I believe that models should be as easy as possible (like in mvc pattern) without any logic and so on (but again, if it should be in that way, maybe model should be only interface?). And ViewModels should have only code for data manipulation to expose data in friendly format to view and convert it back to model. So where rest of the logic should exist? Thank you all in advance for explaining this thing. And in order to put some code to my post, below is interface that I'm using in that .dll file

```
public interface IScope
{
    event EventHandler NewDataInBuffer;
    bool Destroy();
    bool Connect();
    bool Disconnect();
    bool StartCapture();
    bool StopCapture();
    string ScopeName { get; }
    IParameter<float> CurrentVoltageLimit { get; }
    IParameter<int> DataSamplesPerDiv { get; }

    List<IParameter<Config.Timebase>> AvailableTimebaseSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<Config.Coupling>> AvailableCoupleSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<Config.Slope>> AvailableTriggerSlopeSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<Config.VerticalSensitivity>> AvailableSenitivitySettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<Config.TriggerMode>> AvailableTriggerModeSettings { get; }
    List<IParameter<Config.RecordLength>> AvailableRecordLength { get; }


    IParameter<Config.Timebase> TimeBase { get; set; }
    IParameter<Config.Coupling> Couple { get; set; }
    IParameter<Config.Slope> TriggerSlope { get; set; }
    IParameter<Config.VerticalSensitivity> Sensitivity { get; set; }
    IParameter<Config.TriggerMode> TriggerMode { get; set; }
    IParameter<Config.RecordLength> RecordLength { get; set; }
    int TriggerPosition { get; set; }
    float TriggerLevel { get; set; }
}


public interface IParameter<T>
{
    string ParameterName { get; }
    string ParameterValue { get; }
    string ParameterUnit { get; }
    bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    T GetParameter { get; }
}
```

Comment: Understanding MVVM is a journey. As you see the reasons for the components it helps you build according to a plan. To be fair it can be a pain as well. Josh Smith spent 100 hours writing this article on MVVM, I'd start there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Laurent Bugnion's MVVM Light is also helpful. http://www.mvvmlight.net/

Comment: I usually use View - ViewModel - Service layer. In that case VM fetch data via Service from storage/device/c++ library... to provide these data (sorted, modified, filtered, ...) to View in a form it needs.

Comment: Service approach is defo a good way to access data, it comes especially handy when you need to open file from your ViewModel, service can handle that and viewModel remains view specific dlls free. One thing to remember though, once you're done, it will be worth it. Welcome to WPF world.